# Ninject: Bind Constructor Argument to Property of Other Object

Tags: c#, ninject

I have an `IConfig` object that contains settings used throughout my application. At the moment, I inject the entire object into the constructor of each object that needs it, as follows:

```
public interface IConfig 
{
    string Username { get; }
    string Password { get; }
    //... other settings
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    private readonly string username;
    private readonly string password;

    public Foo(IConfig config)
    {
        this.username = config.Username;
        this.password = config.Password;
    }
}
```

The downside is that `IConfig` contains a large number of settings because it's deserialised from an overall config file, so injecting the entire object is unnecessary. What I'd like to do is change the constructor to `Foo(string username, string password)` so that it only receives the settings it needs. This also makes creating `Foo` objects for testing much easier (not having to set up `IConfig` just to create `Foo`). I'd like to bind the constructor arguments directly in my `NinjectModule`, something like the following:

```
public class MyModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IConfig>().To<JsonConfig>()
            .InSingletonScope();

        Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>()
            .WithConstructorArgument("username", IConfig.Username)
            .WithConstructorArgument("password", IConfig.Password);
    }
}
```

Obviously this code doesn't work, but how would I go about doing what I wanted?

My original idea was to use the `NinjectModule.Kernel` to get the `IKernel` then get an instance of my `IConfig` object and inject the properties as required, but the object returned by `NinjectModule.Kernel` has no `Get<T>()` method.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are on the right track:

The `Kernel.Get<T>()` method is an extension method defined on the `ResolutionExtensions` in the `Ninject` namepsace so with adding the `using Ninject;` it is available in your module as well.

But instead of the `Module.Kernel` you should use the `IContext` provided in the second overload of `WithConstructorArgument` to get the `Kernel`:

```
Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("username", 
                             context => context.Kernel.Get<IConfig>().Username)
    .WithConstructorArgument("password", 
                             context => context.Kernel.Get<IConfig>().Password);
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. The `IConfig` object created in the lambda contains all default values (empty strings for those settings). If I just do a normal Kernel.Get<IConfig> now that I've added `using Ninject` this does work properly. Should I invest the effort to get the `context` version working, is there any advantage?

Comment: It should work with `context.Kernel`, I will have a look into it. How the values in `IConfig` gets pupulated? Are you using multiple Kernels?

Comment: Just created a simple test project and this does work. Must be something specific to my particular solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This could be a good candiate for the [Interface segregation principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

In this case, define another interface such as an `ICredentialConfig` containing just the `Username` and `Password` properties, then make `IConfig` implement this interface.

```
public Interface ICredentialConfig
{
   string Username { get; }
   string Password { get; }
}

public Interface IConfig : ICredentialConfig
{
   //... other settings
}
```

Now make `Foo` dependant on `ICredentialConfig` instead of `IConfig`.
You can then:

1. Inject your `JsonConfig` using Ninject, instead of having hardcoded parameter names.
2. Implement/Mock an `ICredentialConfig` for instantiating `Foo` in tests, instead of having to implement the full `IConfig` interface.