# Inject binding as constructor parameter into two another bindings

Tags: c#, binding, ninject

I use in my application Ninject as IoC container.
I have bindings for database context, unit of work and repositories.
It looks as follows:

```
// Database
Kernel.Bind<IDbConnection>().To<SqlConnection>();
Kernel.Bind<IDatabaseContext>().To<DapperContext>();

Kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();

// Repositories
Kernel.Bind<IUserCommandRepository>().To<UserCommandRepository>();
```

Now, I want to pass the same instance of DatabaseContext to UnitOfWork and repositories.
I found this solution: [Ninject: Bind Constructor Argument to Property of Other Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649261/ninject-bind-constructor-argument-to-property-of-other-object) but it does not work for me. When I run this code:

```
public RegisterCommandHandler(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IUserCommandRepository userCommandRepository)
{
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    _userCommandRepository = userCommandRepository;
}
```

UnitOfWork context is different than in repository context.
So in my binding class I created local var which gets instance of databaseContext, and I pass this var as constructor parameter into unit of work and repositories.
Final code looks like this:

```
// Database
Kernel.Bind<IDbConnection>().To<SqlConnection>();
Kernel.Bind<IDatabaseContext>().To<DapperContext>();

// Gets database context
var databaseContext = Kernel.Get<IDatabaseContext>();

Kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().WithConstructorArgument("context", databaseContext);

// Repositories
Kernel.Bind<IUserCommandRepository>().To<UserCommandRepository>().WithConstructorArgument("context", databaseContext);
```

It works perfectly, but I'm not sure if it is the best practice of binding dependencies using Ninject :)
So my question is, if there is another solution to solve this issue.
Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirements, you need to have same instance of `IDataBaseContext` injected in all dependent objects. That's what Singleton scope is for.

So maybe instead of directly setting constructor argument you can configure binding for `IDatabaseContext` to always resolve singleton instance:

```
Kernel.Bind<IDatabaseContext>().To<DapperContext>().InSingletonScope();
```

Comment: Jure - this is solution that I was looking for. Thanks a lot :)